# Grails - Using a VARCHAR2 field as table identifier - foreign key relationship fails

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm

I am integrated with a legacy Oracle database which uses assigned VARCHAR2 values for primary keys.  I am creating a one-to-many relationship with this existing table.  The legacy table is called Applications (which I may not alter) and the new table is called Projects.  Many projects may be assigned to one application.

When GORM creates the Project table it is creating a NUMBER column for the foreign key, application_id, even though this is a VARCHAR2 field in the Applications table.

```
class Application {
   static hasMany = [projects : Project];  // does not fix problem
   String application_id; 
   ...
   static mapping = {
      table 'applications'
      version false
      id (column:'application_id')
   }
   static constraints = {
      application_id(maxSize:16,blank:false,unique:true,type:"string",generator:"assigned")
   }
   ...
}

class Project {
   Application application;
   ...
}
```

When I compile the app I get warnings like this:
Unsuccessful: alter table project add constraint FKED904B1956694CB5 foreign key (application_id)
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

When I run the app and click on Application controller I get this error:
SQL state [99999]; error code [17059]; Fail to convert to internal representation; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation

When I click on Project | create I get this error:
Fail to convert to internal representation; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation at /project/create:172

So how can I set the Project class to expect a VARCHAR2 foreign key for the Application?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you dont use a id from type 'String'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [site](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-problem-with-String-primary-key-td1370256.html). Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction in the Application class... in case anyone else searches for this:

```
class Application {
   static hasMany = [projects : Project];  
   String application_id; 
   String id                  // <--- part of solution

   static mapping = {
      id column:'application_id',generator:'assigned'  // <--- part of solution
   }

   static constraints = {
      application_id(maxSize:16,blank:false,unique:true)  // <--- part of solution
      columns {                                           // <--- part of solution  
                id type:'text'
                application_id type:'text'
              }
   }
```